# NiFi doesn't start on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: apache-nifi

I have installed NiFi using Homebrew following the instructions on [this](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/getting-started.html#for-linuxmacos-users) page.

Once I go start NiFi using

```
nifi start
```

I get the following:

```
Java home: /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
NiFi home: /usr/local/Cellar/nifi/1.15.0/libexec

Bootstrap Config File: /usr/local/Cellar/nifi/1.15.0/libexec/conf/bootstrap.conf

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi
```

I also see this error in the nifi-app.log

```
2021-12-08 13:06:37,463 ERROR [Write-Ahead Local State Provider Maintenance] o.a.n.c.s.p.l.WriteAheadLocalStateProvider Failed to checkpoint Write-Ahead Log used to stor$
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./state/local/partition-0/1.journal (No such file or directory)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
        at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog$Partition.rollover(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:788)
        at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.checkpoint(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:534)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.state.providers.local.WriteAheadLocalStateProvider$CheckpointTask.run(WriteAheadLocalStateProvider.java:286)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Mine was due to the 8443 being occupied. I think, you can either find what's using the 8443 or you can try to change the port `nifi.web.https.port=8443` in `./bin/conf/nifi.properties` to something else. I hope it helps if you are still facing the issues.